# why does sorting cost me 70%?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a view that is very slow:

```
ALTER  view [dbo].[TAT] as
WITH d AS ( SELECT TAT = CASE WHEN TAT > 191 THEN 192 ELSE TAT END,
   [MONTH entered],
   [YEAR] = DATEPART(yyyy,[datetime entered])
  FROM [SalesDWH].[dbo].[TurnAround] TurnAround
  left outer join hermes.lom.dbo.lom_specimen Lom
  on TurnAround.[specimen id] = lom.specimen
  LEFT outer join SalesDWH.dbo.Isomers Isomers
  on TurnAround.[specimen id] = Isomers.[accession id]
  WHERE lom.specimen is null
  and isomers.[accession id] is null
 -- GROUP BY CASE WHEN TAT > 191 THEN 192 ELSE TAT END 
    --[datetime entered],[Month Entered]
),
n AS ( SELECT TOP (192) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_columns ORDER BY [object_id]
)
SELECT TAT = n.n,

  [MONTH entered],
  [YEAR]

FROM n LEFT OUTER JOIN d 
ON n.n = d.TAT  



GO
```

When I look at the execution plan, it tells me that that one of the steps which is SORTING costs me 70%.

When I inspect the SORTING step it says my ORDER BY is:

```
[SalesDWH].[dbo].[QuickLabDump].Specimen ID Ascending, [SalesDWH].[dbo].[QuickLabDump].Date Entered Ascending, [SalesDWH].[dbo].[QuickLabDump].Time Entered Ascending, [SalesDWH].[dbo].[QuickLabDump].Date Completed Ascending, [SalesDWH].[dbo].[QuickLabDump].Time Completed Ascending, [SalesDWH].[dbo].[QuickLabDump].Practice Name Ascending, [SalesDWH].[dbo].[QuickLabDump].Practice Code Ascending, [SalesDWH].[dbo].[QuickLabDump].Order Count Ascending, [SalesDWH].[dbo].[QLMLISMapping].MLIS Practice ID Ascending, [SalesDWH].[dbo].[adjustedtime].TimeDifference Ascending
```

But I haven't specified an ORDER BY anywhere.

**Questions:**

1. Why does it say ASCENDING for ORDER BY if I don't have any ORDER BY's?
2. How do I speed this view up?

I don't know if this information is needed, but the above view is querying another view called `TURNAROUND`:

```
USE [SalesDWH]
GO

/****** Object:  View [dbo].[TurnAround]    Script Date: 05/25/2012 15:32:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO




ALTER VIEW [dbo].[TurnAround]
AS
SELECT     dbo.QuickLabDump.[Specimen ID], DATEPART(yyyy, dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Entered]) AS [Year Entered], CAST(CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Entered] AS DATE) 
                      AS DATETIME) + CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Time Entered] AS TIME) AS [DateTime Entered], CAST(CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Completed] AS DATE) AS DATETIME) 
                      + CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Time Completed] AS TIME) AS [DateTime Completed], dbo.QuickLabDump.[Practice Code] AS [QL Practuce Code], 
                      dbo.QLMLISMapping.[MLIS Practice ID], DATEPART(m, dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Entered]) AS [Month Entered], ROUND(CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, 
                      CAST(CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Entered] AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Time Entered] AS TIME), 
                      CAST(CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Completed] AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Time Completed] AS TIME)) AS FLOAT) / 60, 0) AS TAT, 
                      ROUND(CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, CAST(CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Entered] AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST('9:00AM' AS TIME), 


                      CAST(CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Completed] AS DATE) AS DATETIME) 
                      + CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Time Completed] AS TIME)) AS float) / 60, 0) 

                      AS [Hours TurnAround Since 9AM], TAT9AMStateAdjusted=                   



                      ROUND(CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, CAST(CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Entered] AS DATE) AS DATETIME) 
                      + CAST('9:00AM' AS TIME),                                            
                      CAST(CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Completed] AS DATE) AS DATETIME) 
                      + CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Time Completed] AS TIME)) AS float) / 60, 0)                         


                      +dbo.adjustedtime.timedifference
                      ,dbo.QuickLabDump.[Order Count], CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(D, - (1 * DATEPART(dw, dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Entered])) + 6,
                       dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Entered]), 1) AS [Week Ending]
FROM         dbo.QuickLabDump 
             INNER JOIN dbo.QLMLISMapping 
             ON dbo.QuickLabDump.[Practice Code] = dbo.QLMLISMapping.[Quicklab ID]
             left outer join dbo.AccountState
             on dbo.QuickLabDump.[Practice Code]=dbo.AccountState.[Account]
             left outer join dbo.AdjustedTime 
             ON dbo.AccountState.[state]=dbo.adjustedtime.[state]
WHERE     (dbo.QuickLabDump.[Practice Code] NOT LIKE 'test%') AND (dbo.QuickLabDump.[Specimen ID] NOT LIKE 'of%') AND (dbo.QuickLabDump.Outcome <> 'rejected')
GROUP BY dbo.QuickLabDump.[Specimen ID], dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Entered], dbo.QuickLabDump.[Time Entered], dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Completed], 
                      dbo.QuickLabDump.[Time Completed], dbo.QuickLabDump.[Practice Name], dbo.QuickLabDump.[Practice Code], dbo.QuickLabDump.[Order Count], 
                      dbo.QLMLISMapping.[MLIS Practice ID],dbo.adjustedtime.timedifference
HAVING      (dbo.QuickLabDump.[Order Count] = MAX(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Order Count])) OR
                      (dbo.QuickLabDump.[Order Count] IS NULL)




GO
```

Here are the table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QuickLabDump](
    [Specimen ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Client Key] [int] NULL,
    [Outcome] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Medications] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Date Collected] [date] NULL,
    [Time Collected] [time](0) NULL,
    [Date Entered] [date] NULL,
    [Time Entered] [time](0) NULL,
    [Date Completed] [date] NULL,
    [Time Completed] [time](0) NULL,
    [Test Date] [date] NULL,
    [Test Time] [time](0) NULL,
    [Practice Name] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Practice Code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Requesting Physician] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Other Medications] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Order Comments] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Reference Number] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Order Count] [int] NULL,
    [QuickLabDumpID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Source] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MLIS] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_QuickLabDump_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [QuickLabDumpID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query analyzer is showing you that the sorting is occurring on your Group BY.

You should test\create indexes on the fields that the group by is using in order to increase performance.

Here is more detailed explanation on how Group By can create sorting. [Link](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/24/syndicated/500/posts/12126/sql-server-2012-detecting-sort-warnings-with-extended-events-sortwarning-event.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The columns you see sorted are the columns in TurnAround's `GROUP BY` clause. The simplest way to perform a `GROUP BY` is first sort by the group columns, then split the rows per group, and finally calculate the aggregates per group, and in this case, it looks like that's exactly what the DB is doing.

Comment: thank you this is great information. how can i speed up the view?

Comment: The first thing I'd try is running the index tuning wizard (on a test environment), apply its recommendations, and see if they help. If they help, figure out exactly which of its recommendations was worthwhile and why. If they don't help, think carefully about what your view is supposed to do. It's not easily readable, so I can't really say whether your current definition is the most sensible one.

Comment: It's an option after executing a query in the SQL Server Management Studio, but I don't have that on this computer, so I can't tell you exactly where the menu item is and what it's named right now.

Comment: it wants a place where i stored the WORKLOAD file or table, what is this and how do i create one?

Answer (score 2):

Your group by and  (outer) joins may be the cause for the sorting, do you have any matching indexes on the columns you're using? If you post a full definition of the tables (including the indexes and keys/constraints) it would be less guesswork to find the issue.

Comment: lucero can you please tell me waht you mean by matching indexes? you mean indexes on the joined columns?

Comment: i just posted table defintion for the main table

Comment: If that is the complete table definition, then you don't have any sensible indexes defined, and it is no wonder that the queries are slow. However in general the code looks quite messy and a group by with that many columns is a code smell - you may be able to get what you need by using a different approach (maybe by using window functions). In general a spec what the output is meant to be would be helpful in understanding the view.

Comment: Please [Google](http://tinyurl.com/bngheen) for trivial "what is" questions - it will return much more valuable information than someone (including me) explaining it here.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure you know, I see an order by:

```
,
n AS ( SELECT TOP (192) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_columns ORDER BY [object_id]
)
```

Comment: what would that part look like if i get rid of the ORDER BY?

Comment: I even see two in there... one for the window function and one for the output.

Comment: @Lucero thank you. would it break anything if i get rid of it?

Comment: @Артём Царионов, without knowing what that view really is supposed to do and without a proper analysis of the code I frankly cannot tell if it would break what it is doing.